# Using temporary workdir on python

Tags: python, database, module, operating-system

Its possible on python to set the workdir (os.chdir('path')) like setting a local variable? I mean, its possible to use different directory only when calling a function?

i.e I have:

```
foo_function
    |
    module1---a.json
    |         |
    |         b.csv
    |
    module2---a.json
    |          |
    |         b.csv
    module3
```

I want (example):

```
my_path_1 = '/module1/'
my_path_2 = '/module2/'
def foo(a,b,my_path):
    os.chdir('my_path')
    os.mkdir('csv')
    os.mkdir('json')
    shutil.move(a+'.json','json')
    shutil.move(b+'.csv','csv')
```

And now if I call, for example, a function B which deletes module3, simply deletes that, and not use the new directory of 'my_path' in search of module3 (last call of foo)

Comment: So you want a `chdir` that's only effective for the scope of the function it's called from?

Comment: It's probably a better idea to just `os.mkdir(os.path.join(my_path, 'csv'))` instead of keep changing your working directory.

Comment: I've done this with a context manager, that may be one avenue to consider

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason to change the present working directory. You can easily achieve this task without it. Just look for using absolute paths instead of relative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a context manager to do that:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def temp_chdir(path):
    prev = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(path)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        os.chdir(prev)

 with temp_chdir("~/some_dir"):
    funcion_a()
```

or make a decorator

```
def chdir_dec(path):

    def decorator(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def _fn(*args, **kwargs):
            with temp_chdir(path):
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return _fn

    return decorator

# example ... 

@chdir_dec('../some_path')
def function_a():
    os.system("ls")
```

Answer (score 0):

unless you HAVE to change the directory, it would better to use absolute paths.

```
def foo(a,b,my_path):
    csv_dir = os.path.join(my_path, 'csv')
    json_dir = os.path.join(my_path, 'json')

    os.mkdir(csv_dir)
    os.mkdir(json_dir)

    shutil.move(os.path.join(my_path, a+'.json'), json_dir)
    shutil.move(os.path.join(my_path, b+'.csv'),' csv_dir)
```